# How to add values of an array up?

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
array(450) 
{
  [0]              array(7) 
  {
    ["team1_id"]   int(1)
    ["team2_id"]   int(2)
    ["wins"]       int(2)
    ["draws"]      int(0)
    ["losses"]     int(0)
    ["version_id"] int(24)
    ["serie_id"]   int(2)
  }
  [1]              array(7) 
  {
    ["team1_id"]   int(1)
    ["team2_id"]   int(3)
    ["wins"]       int(1)
    ["draws"]      int(0)
    ["losses"]     int(1)
    ["version_id"] int(24)
    ["serie_id"]   int(2)
  }
  [2]              array(7) 
  {
    ["team1_id"]   int(1)
    ["team2_id"]   int(4)
    ["wins"]       int(0)
    ["draws"]      int(2)
    ["losses"]     int(0)
    ["version_id"] int(24)
    ["serie_id"]   int(2)
  }
  [3]              array(7) 
  {
    ["team1_id"]   int(1)
    ["team2_id"]   int(2)
    ["wins"]       int(1)
    ["draws"]      int(0)
    ["losses"]     int(1)
    ["version_id"] int(23)
    ["serie_id"]   int(2)
  }
  [4]              array(7) 
  {
    ["team1_id"]   int(1)
    ["team2_id"]   int(3)
    ["wins"]       int(1)
    ["draws"]      int(0)
    ["losses"]     int(1)
    ["version_id"] int(23)
    ["serie_id"]   int(2)
  }
  [5]              array(7) 
  {
    ["team1_id"]   int(1)
    ["team2_id"]   int(4)
    ["wins"]       int(0)
    ["draws"]      int(0)
    ["losses"]     int(2)
    ["version_id"] int(23)
    ["serie_id"]   int(2)
  }
```

The code is just one excerpt - the array has 450 elements. I want to get a new array where the values of wins, draws, losses are added up for elements where the team1_id, team2_id and serie_id are the same. The version_id is irrelevant.

In the end the excerpt should then 3 elements and not 6.

How can I do this fast and elegant?

Edit:

Sorry, here is what I have tried. But the problem is that I only take team1_id into account but I need the combination of team1_id, team2_id and serie_id which then should be added up. Should i then need to do: `if ($bla[$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']][$standing['serie_id']])` ?

```
  foreach ($standings as $standing) {

    if (!isset($bla[$standing['team1_id']])) {          
        $bla[$standing['team1_id']]['team1_id'] = $standing['team1_id'];
        $bla[$standing['team1_id']]['team2_id'] = $standing['team2_id'];
        $bla[$standing['team1_id']]['wins'] = $standing['wins'];
        $bla[$standing['team1_id']]['draws'] = $standing['draws'];
        $bla[$standing['team1_id']]['losses'] = $standing['losses'];
        $bla[$standing['team1_id']]['serie_id'] = $standing['serie_id'];
    } else {
        $bla[$standing['team1_id']]['wins']     += $standing['wins'];
        $bla[$standing['team1_id']]['draws']    += $standing['draws'];
        $bla[$standing['team1_id']]['losses']   += $standing['losses'];         
    }
    return $bla;

}
```

Comment: With a `foreach()` loop.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771284/how-to-add-values-in-multidimensional-array) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695140/how-can-i-add-all-the-values-in-an-array).

Comment: it looks like is somebody's work to look for possible duplicates like if that is a crime and just start yelling "PSSIBLE DUPLICATES FOUNDED HERE" so everybody can come and start down voting the question to the point where that user is no longer allowed to ask anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
function concatenateResults($standings) {
    $conc = array();
    foreach ($standings as $standing) {

        if (!isset($conc[$standing['serie_id']][$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']])) {           
            $conc[$standing['serie_id']][$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']]['team1_id']  = $standing['team1_id'];
            $conc[$standing['serie_id']][$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']]['team2_id']  = $standing['team2_id'];
            $conc[$standing['serie_id']][$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']]['wins']      = $standing['wins'];
            $conc[$standing['serie_id']][$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']]['draws']     = $standing['draws'];
            $conc[$standing['serie_id']][$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']]['losses']        = $standing['losses'];
            $conc[$standing['serie_id']][$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']]['serie_id']  = $standing['serie_id'];
        } else {
            $conc[$standing['serie_id']][$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']]['wins']      += $standing['wins'];
            $conc[$standing['serie_id']][$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']]['draws']         += $standing['draws'];
            $conc[$standing['serie_id']][$standing['team1_id']][$standing['team2_id']]['losses']        += $standing['losses'];         
        }
    }//foreach
        return $conc;   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($main_array as $array) {
    $new_array[] = array("team1_id" => $array["team1_id"], "team2_id" => $array["team2_id"], "serie_id" => $array["serie_id"], "total" => ((int)$array["wins"] + (int)$array["draws"] + (int)$array["losses"]));
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

Then in your `new_array`, you could access the total like so:

```
$first_total = $new_array[0]["total"];
```

[More documentation on the foreach() loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

**Note:** I did not test this, just going off prior knowledge